# How do @-references work?

Tags: support, faq

In comments, it is possible to use @-references to get the attention of a user.

Which users can be referred using *@* followed by the username?
Are there users that are automatically notified of a comment?
How do I notify a user with a username containing spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Which users can be referred using @ followed by the username?

The users that can be notified using a @-reference are:

- In questions

  - any user who edited the question
  - the moderator who closed the question
  - any commenter who wrote a comment for the same question
- In answers

  - any user who edited the answer
  - any commenter who wrote a comment for the same answer

#### Are there users that are automatically notified of a comment?

The users who are automatically notified of a new comment are:

- the author of the post
- in the case of comments between two users, the user who wrote the previous comment
- if a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person is also notified if @name is forgotten

#### How do I notify a user with a username containing spaces?

When the user name contains spaces, to get the user notified the username needs to be written without any spaces. This means, for example, that a user using *this is a name with spaces* as username will be notified with @thisisanamewithspaces.
Any single punctuation character following the name is ignored. This means that the following comments will notify *name*.

> @name: This is a comment.

> @name, This is a comment.

> @name. This is a comment.

<sub>[Reference: [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) on Meta Stack Overflow.]</sub>